# File.WriteAllText throws UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: .net, windows, file-access

Doing `File.WriteAllText` to a remote path throws `UnauthorizedAccessException`. When I open the file in notepad I can edit it without a problem. The process that's trying to modify the file is running as my own user account, so it should be able to access it.

Comment: post your code to help troubleshoot

Comment: Nothing to post, it's simple a call to File.WriteAllText on a file (not directory). It might be opened by another process, but it shouldn't be locked since I'm modifying it from notepad successfully.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx), `UnauthorizedAccessException` can also be caused by:

> ```
> path specified a file that is read-only.
>
> -or- 
>
> This operation is not supported on the current platform.
>
> -or- 
>
> path specified a directory.
> ```

Is it possible one of these conditions is the cause of your problem?

Comment: Thank you, this saved me. :)

Answer (score 14):

The `UnauthorizedAccessException` is also thrown if the file has the "hidden" attribute set. Don't ask me why...

Comment: Thank you so much!
I spend a good day puzzling over why every call after the first to this code was failing with unauth:
File.WriteAllText(tempFilePath, exportCommand);

   File.SetAttributes(tempFilePath, FileAttributes.Hidden);

Comment: @Hellfire If this helped, an upvote will help future visitors find the answer quicker and also will be appreciated by me ;)

Comment: Oops thought I had, enjoy! :)

Comment: Wow, that's obscure.  That's what my problem was...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you also get this exception (although its not documented) if the file is being locked by another process or thread.

Make sure nothing else has opened the file in a manner that prohibits writing.  Notepad is not a good test for seeing if a file is locked, since it will open a locked file (ie: read-only files are fine).

Comment: In notepad I can actually edit the file. Why can't I modify it from .Net?

Comment: Try SAVING the file.  Notepad will always open a file unless it's locked for exclusive read (which is very rare) - but you won't be able to save it over the top, usually - you'll have to use SaveAs...